# What is the '¤' character?

Tags: keyboard, characters, ascii

Lately I've started wondering about the ¤ character which is shift+4 on my Norwegian keyboard (it's also present on [several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout), including the U.S. International keyboard layout). I've never seen a use for it, yet for some reason someone decided it was important enough to have it put in such a central place on the keyboard. What is this character called, and what purpose does it have?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the [currency sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign)

> A currency sign is a graphic symbol
>   used as a shorthand for a currency's
>   name.

Also from [Currency (typography):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_(typography))

> The currency sign (¤) is a character
>   used to denote a currency, when the
>   symbol for a particular currency is
>   unavailable.
>
> The symbol is available on some
>   keyboard layouts, for example French,
>   Danish, Norwegian, Swedish and Finnish
>   keyboards, because it is used in
>   business applications.

Comment: The Norweigan currency is a kr for krone though. Is this a fraction of the krone? This question got my interest.

Comment: @JoeTaylor: I think it's a symbol for a "generic" currency. A currency that has no symbol. But you're right, might be that the fractions of the Kronen are using that symbol though...

Comment: It's definitely not used for Norwegian currency, neither Krone nor Øre (which is 1/100 krone).

Comment: Another way to think of it is a placeholder for a currency symbol. The equivalent of `<insert currency symbol here>`.

Answer (score 1):

Pillow character in the Travel Industry designates a Guarantee Sell vendor. Allowing visual confirmation of booking a transaction with a vendor that guarantees reservation.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "pillow" and is used, at least, in some Global Distribution Systems for the Travel Industry.

Source: I work in the Travel Industry.

Comment: It's generally called a "[Currency Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_%28typography%29)" in my experience. What is it used for in the travel industry?